# DataFolder class not detecting training samples

Tags: python-bob

I am trying to reproduce the experiments in the paper Cross Modal Focal Loss for RGBD Face Anti-Spoofing (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.00948.pdf) . I've pointed my preprocessed directory to point to the mc-pixbis-224 preprocessed data in order to train the RGBDMH - CMFL model .I've selected to train the grandtest protocol and pointed the annotations directory to PROTOCOL-grand_test-curated.csv file .  However , my DataFolder class fails to load any training samples as the length of dataset when printed is 0 .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/train_generic.py", line 22, in <module>
    sys.exit(bob.learn.pytorch.scripts.train_generic.main())
  File "/home/hazeeq/anaconda3/envs/bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bob/learn/pytorch/scripts/train_generic.py", line 150, in main
    shuffle=True,
  File "/home/hazeeq/anaconda3/envs/bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 262, in __init__
    sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/hazeeq/anaconda3/envs/bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py", line 104, in __init__
    "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))
ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0
(bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021) hazeeq@hazeeq-U3033:~/test/bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021$
```

Line 152 of train_generic.py refers to this section of the code where dataloader["train"] fails to be loaded with the proper DataLoader object within the 'else' statement:

```
  # Which device to use is figured out at this point, no need to use `use-gpu` flag anymore
    # get data
    if hasattr(configuration, "dataset"):
        dataloader = {}

        if not do_crossvalidation:

            logger.info(
                "There are {} training samples".format(
                    len(configuration.dataset["train"])
                )
            )

            dataloader["train"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                configuration.dataset["train"],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_workers=num_workers,
                shuffle=True,
            )

        else:
            dataloader["train"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                configuration.dataset["train"],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_workers=num_workers,
                shuffle=True,
            )
            dataloader["val"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                configuration.dataset["val"],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_workers=num_workers,
                shuffle=True,
            )

            logger.info(
                "There are {} training samples".format(
                    len(configuration.dataset["train"])
                )
            )
            logger.info(
                "There are {} validation samples".format(
                    len(configuration.dataset["val"])
                )
            )

    else:
        logger.error("Please provide a dataset in your configuration file !")
        sys.exit()

    assert hasattr(configuration, "optimizer")

    # train the network
    if hasattr(configuration, "network"):
        trainer = GenericTrainer(
            configuration.network,
            configuration.optimizer,
            configuration.compute_loss,
            learning_rate=learning_rate,
            device=device,
            verbosity_level=verbosity_level,
            tf_logdir=output_dir + "/tf_logs",
            do_crossvalidation=do_crossvalidation,
            save_interval=save_interval,
        )
        trainer.train(dataloader, n_epochs=epochs, output_dir=output_dir, model=model)
    else:
        logger.error("Please provide a network in your configuration file !")
        sys.exit()
```

The code also reports multiple missing files , so I am not sure if there are any missing files that should be part of the MC-pixbis-224 preprocessed data . Here I have attached some of the missing file prompts , there are more missing files than the ones showed below .

```
...............................HLDI self.annotation_directory ./hqwmca-protocols-csv/PROTOCOL-grand_test-curated.csv
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/02.04.19/1_03_0064_0000_06_01_013-e3a1456b.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/01.04.19/1_03_0001_0000_07_00_001-c8bd4c01.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/02.04.19/1_03_0001_0000_06_01_001-48c7d79c.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/11.03.19/1_03_0523_0018_08_00_004-315ad7b2.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/02.04.19/1_03_0002_0000_06_01_002-173e70ed.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/11.10.19/1_01_0002_0000_00_00_000-51e86383.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/11.10.19/1_01_0002_0000_00_00_000-7517b634.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/07.10.19/1_01_0077_0000_00_00_000-9f7b92f8.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/07.10.19/1_01_0077_0000_00_00_000-d416451d.hdf5
Missing file: /home/Dataset/FaceAntiSpoofing/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/11.10.19/1_01_0084_0000_00_00_000-305a3a31.hdf5
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV files are not annotations, they are just showing the distribution of files in different folds in each of the protocols if you want to use the datasets outside `bob`. Moreover, the `MC-pixbis-224` preprocessed files do not correspond to the RGB-D data, it corresponds to an earlier paper. For RGB-D data you have to access the RAW data, and preprocess the data using the documentation.

Regards,
Anjith

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I've obtained permission to download both the WMCA and HQWMCA dataset , however the HQWMCA dataset does not provide the raw data to do preprocessing . May I ask how would one load the WMCA rgb-d data for this particular model ?

Comment: Hi,  for rgb-d specifically, you have to ask for the raw data and not preprocessed files. ANd these have to be sent in an HDD, since its 3-4TB.

Comment: Can I confirm that this applies for both WMCA and HQWMCA datasets in order to run the cmfl model ?